# Xcode4: two entities with "required" relationship ... failing to be maintained by Core Data?

Tags: core-data

EDIT: might be fixed in latest Xcode 4.0.2 (just released) - I'm downloading this out now, and will re-edit once I've tested it.

Create two entities (call them "Manager" and "Employee", to stick with Apple's docs).

Create a relationship, "worksFor" from Manager (1) to Employee (many), and mark it as "not optional". (you'll probably need to create 2 relationships, mark 1 as inverse of other)

Hook up an interface using IB, according to Apple's original docs (NB: these don't work any more, but here's an almost exact recreation of the basic setup in Xcode4: http://rgprojection.blogspot.com/2011/04/xcode-4-and-core-data-macos-x.html) and use Bindings (as described in the linked post) to create/add/delete the objects.

Now try to save. ERROR: "worksFor is a required property".

In previous versions of Xcode, this worked as expected: you'd told Xcode that there was a bidirectional relationship, you told it that it was required, and so when it added the "Employee" to the "Manager", it automatically hooked-up the inverse.

Has anyone else worked out how to make Xcode4 do what it's supposed to? Is it an Xcode4 bug? I know that some of the CoreData support in Xcode4 has been deleted, with no replacement (yet), so I'm wondering if this has been deleted too?!

EDIT: here's another project, one I made from scratch, same problem. Although (xcode4 bug, definitely!) this time I created the Relationship in the "grid" editor view rather than the "tree graphical" view... and the generated source code for objects was *different* (should not be the case, obviously)

[second project screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKESS.png)

EDIT2: StackOverflow *was* showing the screenshot above, but has now removed it, you'll have to click on the link. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xcode 4.0.2 seems to have fixed the problem - everything works as expected now, with no changes to code :)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen the problem you describe and I've created several data models under Xcode4. It appears to work just like it did in previous versions in that regard. I think you've got something else going on.

Comment: Just to check: 1. You've got a "Required" relationship, 2. You haven't generated source code for the MO's (although I tried this, and it made no difference - and the source that was generated appeared wrong) 3. the bi-directional stuff "Just Works" ?

Comment: I don't know if I've exactly duplicated your setup but I haven't had any problems with a failure of reverse relationships. They are the standard relationship after all as are required relationships. I think you've got a problem with your data model you are not seeing.

Comment: I just noticed that Apple has released a new version of Xcode, the main change is about CoreData models being generated incorrectly :) - so, hopefully, that will fix this. I'll try it out and post back here.

Comment: Here's hopping. It's probably one of those bugs that only hits a few people depending on where the planets where when they installed. I hate those. People look at you like you're crazy and then it turns out that everybody who installed between 4pm and 5pm on a Tuesday has the bug. Something like that actually happened to me by the way.